# Launch4J creates exe file leading to false positives with VirusTotal?

Tags: java, executable-jar, false-positive

I have an executable jar exported with ecplise (for example my.jar) that I transform to an Windows exe with using lauch4j (for example my.exe).

The my.exe is works correct, but if I load it on virus total, it founds this:

- Jiangmin - TrojanSpy.Java.c
- McAfee-GW-Edition - BehavesLike.Win32.Suspicious-JAR.wc

I have try to use sign4j to sign my.exe created by launch4j.
I have try this command:

```
sign4j.exe --verbose signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f mycertificates.pfx /p mypassword /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll my_signed.exe
```

The tools tell me "Successfully signed" and my_signed.exe result have a different size from my.exe

But if scan my_signed.exe to virus total I obtain same virus:

- Jiangmin - TrojanSpy.Java.c
- McAfee-GW-Edition - BehavesLike.Win32.Suspicious-JAR.wc

Is there a way to use sign4j differently, to avoid such problems? Or is there other way to prevent antivirus false positives?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a common problem, see this [entry](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/192/) from their bugtracker:

> I sometimes receive reports that some protection software complains about my L4J wrapped JAR containing a virus or trojan. At the moment, I receive the following reports:
>
> McAfee-GW-Edition: BehavesLike Win32 Suspicious-JARE.wc
>
> Microsoft: Trojan:Win32/Vigorf.A

The solution suggested there is to use the [comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1090/66/code-signing-for-windows) tool for signing.

Comment: I've try to sign with signtool and with sign4j but if scan signed exe's to virus total I obtain same virus. It's sure to avoid false positives is it necessary sign ?!?

Comment: @RinaldoLisario74 I don't know that. Just telling you what others did ;-)

Comment: I've try this commands but i obtain same problem:

<code>signtool.exe" sign /f myCerticate.pfx /p myPassword /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 myProgram.exe</code>

<code>signtool.exe" sign /f myCerticate.pfx /p myPassword myProgram.exe</code>

Comment: You might want to update your question with that information then. Sorry, but I have no other idea then. Well: besides ... contact the launch4j team directly.

Comment: Thanks, I've tro to contact launch4j team but I not any answers.
Many people have same problems but it's not clear to resolve it.
Bha... I will try wait some others suggestions.
Bye